# Widget used in GWT showcase left menu

Tags: gwt

I would like to develop in GWT a vertical menu similar to the one found on http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html (the left blue menu which first section is "Widgets").

Since it's a GWT showcase, one can assume that left menu is a GWT widget, but which one ?

I have browsed every example and none of them looks like that menu. Any guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the **CellTree widget**!

A demo is actually inside the showcase: [CellTree](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree), but in the example, it has a different style applied:

```
CellTree.Resources res = GWT.create(CellTree.BasicResources.class);
CellTree.Resources res = GWT.create(CellTree.BasicResources.class);
    cellTree = new CellTree(
        new ContactTreeViewModel(selectionModel), null, res);
```

(this stlyes makes the +/- buttons and lets it look like a regular tree)

If you don't apply this style the Cell Tree looks like the left menu.

Comment: I think it's just DisclosurePanels. CellTree widget has additional attributes on the divs, like __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus1. Which is also present in the showcase. But, yeah you can implement it either way. If it's static content, probably just easier with DisclosurePanel, but if it's data backed, then go for a CellTree.

Comment: I'm sure it's the CellTree widget. If you look inside the CSS you see that there are "__gwtCellBasedWidgetImplDispatchingblur" attributes. Also the "Disclosure Panel" is table-based, while the left menue is div- based.
Regarding the implementation, you are right, you could do it with both. The CellTTree isn't the easieast widget to understand and implement so for sinmple task I'd use the Disclosure Panel.

Answer (score 3):

Did you know the Showcase sample is open-source? It's even bundled with the GWT SDK.

The code tells use it's a CellTree within a ScrollPanel (within a DockLayoutPanel within a DockLayoutPanel):

- [The UiBinder template](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.ui.xml#219)
- [The code initializing the CellTree](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/ShowcaseShell.java#182)
- [The code initializing the TreeViewModel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/Showcase.java#108) (including prefetching the split-points for the samples when you expand a category node; and updating the center panel when you select a sample node)
- [the TreeViewModel itself](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/MainMenuTreeViewModel.java)

Answer (score 0):

Looks just like a vertical arrangement of [DisclosurePanel](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel). Here are [the docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html).